# Cassandra keyspace clone within a cluster

Tags: cassandra, replication, nodetool

I've managed to clone a keyspace on a single node test machine by using the snapshot feature of the nodetool.
By clone, I mean same keyspace data with a different name: original: Keyspace1, new: Keyspace2.

If I do the same procedure one a single node within a cluster, will the new keyspace be replicated to all the other nodes? or must I run the procedure on all the nodes within the cluster?

Comment: nodetool snapshot is a local command and only snapshots the sstables on a single node.  You would have to do it on all of your nodes to ensure that you have all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new keyspace schema would be replicated, but you won't have all of your data unless you perform the same operation on all nodes.